# AC L+ and N- difference

Tags: ac, safety, polarity, reverse-polarity

Hey guys i'm on a project in which I have to use Safety Modules.

I'm confused with the pin-out diagram of the safety modules. They reference L and N lines of an AC source. I'm leaving you the data-sheets of two different Safety Modules, both make reference to L and N lines.

http://www.pizzato.com/PizzatoWeb/UserFiles/File/pdf/ZE_GCS01A15/ZE_GCS01A15-ENG_183-206.pdf (page 2)

https://cache.industry.siemens.com/dl/files/885/67585885/att_857967/v1/manual_safety_relay_3SK1_es-MX.pdf (page 50)

The safety Modules should go inside a machine in which the polarity (hot-neutral/L-N) is unknown. What does this mean, or what should I do to use them if I don't know what L and N are?

Comment: I assume this is an industrial project since it requires safety modules.  I've never seen an industrial project where L and N were interchangeable. NFPA79, for example, requires L, N, and GND busses to relate to each other in very specific ways.  Even as far as dictating wire colors.  I expect the safety modules were designed with this in mind, and may not be appropriate when the power feeds are unknown.

Comment: Not sure where he is from, but in much of continental Europe, standard outlets are not polarized, so anything with a plug (as opposed to fixed wiring) can distinguish live vs. neutral.

Comment: get the DC version and power the module from 24V DC

Comment: Power outlets here don't differentiate the live from the neutral. I'll leave you a picture (Chile). http://imaginaisladepascua.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Enchufe-L-Chile.jpg
Maybe @Jasen is the way to go